# Does creating new object reseting properties of class

Tags: java

I am new to OO programming. Suppose I have class and 2d array inside full of values. 
If I create object of a class in another class, is that 2d array going to be empty?
If yes, what is the way to preserve values, while making new instance of a class?

Comment: do you want to preserve value in every instance of your class, like every instance should have the array and all having same values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `static` keyword to make the member variable common across all instances of the class. That way, *every* instance will hold the same values in the array.

Comment: Thanks - let me know if you need any further help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Create a constructor that takes in the array as a parameter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] array = new int[5][10];
        otherClass oc = new otherClass(array);
    }

public class otherClass {

    public otherClass(int[][] a){
        //do stuff with full array
    }
}
```

Comment: I will go with static but nice to know :)

Answer (score 0):

It will be empty. If you define in the class constructor the method which fill the array, always that constructor is thrown, the array will be full of values.

Something like:

```
public myclass() {

int array[] = new int[20];
...
}
```